# VBA (Ms-Access) 2013 Overflow errors

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm building a set of VBA functions to manipulate IP address strings in an MS-Access database and I am having problems with overflow errors whenever the IP address value exceeds the size of an Integer variable.  I've tried to ensure I am using only Long types, but I am still getting these errors.  Here is a very simple demo that fails with an overflow, and I can't figure out why.

```
Public Function BigNumber() As Long
Dim N256 As Long
N256 = 256
BigNumber = N256 * N256 * N256 * N256
End Function
```

I've read other thread that explained VBA may give overflow errors if any of the terms in an expression are too small for the product, but I can't see how that applies in this example.  Can anybody explain?

Comment: Have you done the math? Have you checked the documentation to see what the valid values are (lower and upper) for a long in VBA? I think you're going to find the overflow is correct. (Hint: IP addresses fall between 0 and 255 for a reason.)

Comment: @RacilHilan: That's probably a good idea. I'll clean mine up now. Sorry to have disappointed you. Maybe next time. :-)

Comment: If you're running on 64-bits Access and don't need to be compatible with 32-bits Access, you can use the `LongLong` variable type. It is compatible with way larger numbers.

Comment: Yes, I did RTFM. An Integer variable can be between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647 and a Long variable can be -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. So that is not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, a Long variable can store a value between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647. The result of your calculation is greater than the max, so it overflows:

> 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 = 4,294,967,296

Comment: Yes, I did RTFM. An Integer variable can be between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647 and a Long variable can be -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.  So that is not the issue.

Comment: Where did you read that in VBA a Long can be that large? There is no programming language I'm aware of that gives such a large storage for Long type. That's absolutely incorrect. Here is an [official Microsoft page for data types in Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-the-field-size-ba65e5a7-2e6f-4737-8e72-36b93f966a33).

Comment: You are not aware of many programming languages. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/data-type-summary.  But this did point me to the answer.  It seems that VBA data types are different from Visual Basic data types, and the VBA Long data type is 4 bytes like the Visual Basic Integer data type and the VBA Integer data type is only 2 bytes.   I solved my problem by using the Double data type.

Comment: Yes, of course, I'm not aware of many, depending on the definition of many. I know about 20, among them is VB (classic and .Net) and VBA :-). My last comment had a typo, missing the word "old", so "there is no old programming language", because VBA is an old language that hasn't changed much and still in use in MS Office. The link in your comment is for VB.Net, not VBA. And yes, they're completely different languages (they have similar syntax). There is a huge difference, not only the data types. The link I gave you was for VBA data types.

Comment: Using `Double` can be OK, but be careful how you're using it. It is a floating point type, which means it is approximate, so if you use it with some operations you will get the wrong results. You can try using `Decima` instead. It is a fixed point and accurate like `Long`.